# How to write the result of a function into a variable for further actions?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm

Good evening dear forum users.
The second year of the university began, and with it the assembler began.

The task is as follows: "Call the GetDriveType function. Check the result of the function, if the result is "Removable disk", display the union of the results of the GetComputerName and GetCurrentDirectory functions, otherwise display the union of the results of the GetUserName and GetWindowsDirectory functions."

So far, everything is working out for me, but I still can’t cope with the GetDriveType function. I don’t know how to compare the value received by the function with the value required by the condition of the task

Now two numbers are written in the program, and if one number is equal to the other, then one block of code is executed, and if not, another. I just need to remake this condition and write that if the function returns the result “Removable disk”, then the first block is executed, and if not, the second one.

It would seem that the task is simple, but I still can’t figure it out.
I have an idea to write the result of the function into the variable x, and then compare it with the value I need. But I don't know how to implement it.

If you know an easier way to solve my problem, I'm ready to listen))

P.S. I`m using RadASM IDE for writing code

First.inc file

```
include WINDOWS.inc
include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc
include advapi32.inc

includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib
includelib advapi32.lib

.data
    hello_title db 'Lab №1', 0
    size_buf1 dd 256
    res db 1000 dup(0)

    szbuf1 db 100 dup(0)
    szbuf2 db 255 dup(0)
    szformat_1 db'Computer Name:  %s', 13,10
               db'Current Dir:  %s', 0

    szbuf3 db 100 dup(0)
    szbuf4 db 255 dup(0)
    szformat_2 db'User Name:  %s', 13,10
               db'Windows Dir:  %s', 0
         
    drive db "C:\\", 0

    num1 dword 3
    num2 dword 4
    x dword ?
```

First.asm file

```
.386
.model flat, STDCALL
option casemap :none
include First.inc
include RADbg.inc

.code
Start:
    call main
    invoke ExitProcess,NULL

main proc

    invoke GetDriveType, addr drive

    mov eax, num1
    cmp eax, num2
    jne l1
    invoke GetComputerName, addr szbuf1, addr size_buf1
    invoke GetCurrentDirectory, addr size_buf1, addr szbuf2
    invoke wsprintf, addr res, addr szformat_1, addr szbuf1, addr szbuf2
    invoke MessageBox, 0, addr res, addr hello_title, MB_OK

    jmp l2

l1: invoke GetUserName, addr szbuf3, addr size_buf1
    invoke GetWindowsDirectory,addr szbuf4, addr size_buf1
    invoke wsprintf, addr res, addr szformat_2, addr szbuf3, addr szbuf4
    invoke MessageBox, 0, addr res, addr hello_title, MB_OK
l2:

    ret

main endp
end Start
```

Comment: Why not directly compare eax with the removable drive constant? cmp eax, 2 (or cmp eax, DRIVE_REMOVABLE if your windows.inc has that)?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, YOU'RE GENIUS MAAAN. It's realy works/ Thank you very much)))